# why isnt this regex returning my price value?

Tags: python

```
this is the tag im looking to find with the below regex '<span itemprop="price">34.97</span>'
matches = re.findall(r'<span itemprop="price">\$(\d+)</span>', html)
```

the above has only been tried as it shows as well without the $

Im expecting to see the price 34.97 in this example, but when i run the code, here are the values that are returned (no results are returned)

Highest Price:$0
Lowest Price:$0
200

[]

Comment: can you tell me in which string you are searching with this regex?

Comment: maybe you arent considering decimal values in the regex , think about it and change the regex

Comment: This is the code lines i have        matches = re.findall(r'<span itemprop="price">\$(^\d*\.?\d+$)</span>', html)                           
    prices = map(int, matches)
    info = list(map(int,matches))       And here is where im trying to write it out to the console to see what it found            print("Highest Price:${}".format(max(prices,default=0)))
    print("Lowest Price:${}".format(min(prices,default=0)))
    print(r.status_code)
    print(prices)
    print(info)

Comment: Honestly i dont care if its a number or a string, because there is a slim chance that it may contain words between the tag, so all i want is to return whatever is between the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CPKCEi/1)

```
<span itemprop=\"price\">(\d*\.?\d+)</span>
```

It considers decimals as well as numbers

If you really dont care about what is between the span the here is its regex [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/I11k3r/1)

```
<span itemprop=\"price\">([^<]+)</span>
```

Feel free to adjust it to what ever you require as `re.findall` will return the entire span so you might need a forward and a backward lookup in this regex if you want just the numbers only and not the entire span. But that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to capture 34.97

\d+ does not account for the period between dollars and cents.

Try:
(\d+.\d+)

```
\d+ (one or more digit)
\. (escaped . character so it captures one period)
\d+ (one or more digits)
```

https://pythex.org/

Is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

Both options and suggestions worked above, but after a little testing we found that there may some instances where there is no numerical value in the tag, so opted for the last suggestion
    ([^<]+)

this seems to catch those instances right now and will adjust if needed. we are building a concept spider, so this will do for our testing and demo functionality..